# Encoding issue in CSV angular 2 with ampersand

Tags: javascript, angular, csv, typescript, export-to-csv

Am trying to download a CSV report using Javascript. However, am facing some encoding issues in CSV. Am getting `&` as `&amp;` the following is my JS code. I tried solutions from google but to no avail.

```
JSONToCSVConvertor(ReportTitle, ShowLabel) {
    let csv = [];

    var tableId = document.querySelector('table').getAttribute('id');

    var headers = document.querySelectorAll("table#"+tableId+" tr");

    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {

    var row = [], cols = headers[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++)

        row.push(cols[j].innerHTML);


    csv.push(row.join(", "));   

}

this.downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), sampleTitle);

downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
    var csvFile;
    var downloadLink;

    var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8' + encodeURI(csv);

// Download link
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");


    downloadLink.href = uri;

    downloadLink.download = filename + ".csv";

    // Hide download link
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";

    // Add the link to DOM
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    // Click download link
    downloadLink.click();

    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

How to get the exact special characters in CSV? Any help?

Comment: `encodeURI` doesn't change `&` ... you want `encodeURIComponent` perhaps

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is overkill ...

```
function encodeRFC5987ValueChars(str) {
    return window.encodeURIComponent(str)
        .replace(/['()]/g, window.escape)
        .replace(/\*/g, '%2A')
        .replace(/%(?:7C|60|5E)/g, window.unescape);
}
```